# White Border around Resized Image

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swift4

I'm using the following code to resize an image.But i keep getting a white border at the bottom

```
 func resize(withSize targetSize: NSSize) -> NSImage? {

        let size=NSSize(width: floor((targetSize.width/(NSScreen.main?.backingScaleFactor)!)), height:floor( (targetSize.height/(NSScreen.main?.backingScaleFactor)!)))

        let frame = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: floor(size.width), height: floor(size.height))

        guard let representation = self.bestRepresentation(for: frame, context: nil,hints: nil) else {
            return nil
        }

        let image = NSImage(size: size, flipped: false, drawingHandler: { (_) -> Bool in
            return representation.draw(in: frame)
        })

        return image
    }
```

I have tried using `floor` function to round off the values.But still the same issue.

[image]

Comment: your code will scaleToFit (this will distort your origanal image). Is it intentional?

Comment: @LeoDabus No.... I just want to resize the image...

Comment: This will also take in account the screen scale. If you pass a size of 300x300, the screen scale is @2x  the resulting image will be 600x600. Is it what you want?

Comment: @LeoDabus I passed the screen scale to make sure the image is not 2X scaled as I have a retina screen.Basically I need two functions to resize image keeping aspect ratio and one without preserving the aspect ratio.The output file must be the exact size the user enters in pixels in case of non aspect ratio preservation.. it should be independent of the screen size.

Comment: If you don't take into account the screen scale the result will look pixelated

Comment: @LeoDabus ah... okay.. The core functionality is image resizing .. the image should be the same size irrespective of the machine.

Answer (score 1):

```
extension NSImage {
    func resize(withSize targetSize: NSSize) -> NSImage? {
        let ratioX = targetSize.width / size.width / (NSScreen.main?.backingScaleFactor ?? 1)
        let ratioY = targetSize.height / size.height / (NSScreen.main?.backingScaleFactor ?? 1)
        let ratio = ratioX < ratioY ? ratioX : ratioY
        let canvasSize = NSSize(width: size.width * ratio, height: size.height * ratio)
        let frame = NSRect(origin: .zero, size: canvasSize)
        guard let representation = bestRepresentation(for: frame, context: nil, hints: nil)
        else { return nil }
        return NSImage(size: canvasSize, flipped: false) { _ in representation.draw(in: frame) }
    }
}
```

---

```
let image = NSImage(contentsOf: URL(string: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs4RX.jpg")!)!
let resized = image.resize(withSize: .init(width: 400, height: 300))  // w 267 h 300
```

If you would like to take into account the screen scale just remove the division by `(NSScreen.main?.backingScaleFactor ?? 1)` from the method when calculating ratioX and ratioY

Comment: Thanks.. I just shutdown my machine.Will check tomorrow and get back.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the code. Your issue is somewhere else

Comment: I think the issue is here ... I'm trying to detect and crop square shaped faces based on your old answer https://codeshare.io/G7Kzy1