# Cannot convert value of type 'NSImageInterpolation.Type' to expected argument type '[NSImageRep.HintKey : Any]?'

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swift4

I want to add image interpolation hint as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/14878177/848968

```
 guard let representation = self.bestRepresentation(for: frame, context: nil,hints: NSImageInterpolation) else {
            return nil
```

But i keep getting this exception

```
Cannot convert value of type 'NSImageInterpolation.Type' to expected argument type '[NSImageRep.HintKey : Any]?'
```

Comment: The error it is pretty self explanatory `hints: [.interpolation: NSImageInterpolation.high.rawValue]`

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks.. can you add it as an answer ? Can you help me with this too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61030581/white-border-around-resized-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error it is pretty self explanatory.

```
guard let representation = self.bestRepresentation(for: frame,
                                                   context: nil,
                                                   hints: [.interpolation: NSImageInterpolation.high])
else { return nil }
```